# Python tkinter - Text not showing (GUI)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have no bug errors and I was wondering why 'TIMER' is not showing up in the GUI when I run it. It just shows a white box. I`ve tried searching the forums for an issue similar to mine but I failed to find any.
CODE:

```
import tkinter


class study_timer:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.mainframe = tkinter.Frame(self.master, bg='white')
        self.mainframe.pack(fill = tkinter.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.build_grid()
        self.build_banner()

    def build_grid(self):
        self.mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)

    def build_banner(self):
        banner = tkinter.Label(
            self.mainframe,
            bg='black',
            text='TIMER',
            fg='white',
            font=('Ravie Regular', 30)
        )
        banner.grid(
            row=0, column=0,
            stick='ew',
            padx=10, pady=10
        )

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you instantiate this class anywhere? Is this the whole code? Does the indentation here match your actual code? Does your actual code use the named argument `stick` rather than `sticky`?

Comment: Ive only started python so i dont really understand what you mean by 'instantiate this class', do you mind explaining what this means? Yes my indentation matches the actual code. My code uses stick but I tried changing to sticky and it had no effect when I ran it.

Comment: You define a class and then don't create an object of that class. If the `if __name__...` block is inside the class you never instantiate, it will not be executed until you start instantiating that class. Generally, that block is placed at the outermost indentation level.

Comment: is this what you mean ?
`class study_timer(object):`

Comment: Nope, that's just another way of defining it. I mean creating an object of that class, e.g. `my_study_timer = study_timer(root)`. If you never do that, none of what's in that class will get executed.

Comment: I entered the following at the bottom: `if __name__ == "__main__":
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        my_study_timer = study_timer(root)
        root.mainloop()`
I recieved the following error:   `my_study_timer = study_timer(root)
NameError: name 'study_timer' is not defined`

Comment: Looks good. Make sure that's at the highest indentation level so that the class has finished being defined before you refer to it.

Comment: Correction: even if you never instantiate the class, code at its top level (like the `if __name__...` block) will be executed. However, you would still have to move that particular block out of the class in this case, because you want to _refer_ to that class there, and you can only do that once the class is defined.

Answer (score 2):

You should instantiate an object of the class if you want to run the functions that you defined. The functions are called from constructor(**init**) in your class structure.

Second, if statement's indentation is wrong.

Third, you should send the root object to init function as parameter.

This will work

```
import tkinter


class study_timer:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.mainframe = tkinter.Frame(self.master, bg='white')
        self.mainframe.pack(fill = tkinter.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.build_grid()
        self.build_banner()

    def build_grid(self):
        self.mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)

    def build_banner(self):
        banner = tkinter.Label(
            self.mainframe,
            bg='black',
            text='TIMER',
            fg='white',
            font=('Ravie Regular', 30)
        )
        banner.grid(
            row=0, column=0,
            stick='ew',
            padx=10, pady=10
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    ss = study_timer(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! I just fixed the indentation of "if" and it worked.